# Unexpected nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I'm currently working on my project and I'm new in Ruby on Rails.
I'm working with cart to group same products in a single line item
and took me to this error:

```
    You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
```

I can't understand why the method created cannot be found

line_item_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item =  @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
          :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
          :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The inside of the `Cart` module:

```
 def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

and my view is cart show is

```
<% for item in @cart.line_items %>
<li><%= item.quantity %> &times; <%= item.product.title %></li>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

I seriously I don't know what happen but when I type:

```
def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

This line to be exact it went good in going

`current_item.quantity += 1`

May someone explain what just happened ?

Comment: looks like the quantity doesn't have a value sometimes. does your item model have validations that ensure that it must contain something? otherwise have a look in your db and see if there are any records with missing quantity.

Comment: @ thorsten müller yes it has, it is working fine now the problem is add item at my first attemp it produce an nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal error but when i return to the home page and click for the second attemp it worked fine but didnt count my first attemp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `current_item.quantity += 1` try `current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1`
What I did is that if `current_item.quantity` is `nil`, `current_item.quantity.to_i` will be = 0, else it will get the integer value of current_item.quantity

Comment: thanks i got the error again using the current_item.quantity += 1
then after trying your code it work smooth again :)

Comment: now the problem is add item at my first attemp it produce an nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal error but when i return to the home page and click for the second attemp it worked fine but didnt count my first attemp

Comment: Am sorry, I didn't understand the problem, could you please clarify it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376558/adding-items-to-cart-first-attemp-fail i made a new question for it

Answer (score 0):

From given code, I suspect only following line `current_item.quantity += 1`. I guess it is nil sometimes, that's why you are getting exception.

Make sure the **quantity value is initialized to 1 properly** when you do the following,

```
current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
```

Note: When you look at the log, you can find out the line number where the exception is raised. Inspect the variable used in that line and dig more.