# adding items to cart first attemp fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi im workiing on ruby on rails im just wondering if my add_product is wrong because when i add my product in to my cart at first attemp it fail and give me a

> nil cannot concien bigdecimal error

but clicking return from my browser and add item at the second attemp it worked fine and but didnt count my first attemp of adding my product 
this is my add_product method

my model/cart.rb

```
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first
     if current_item 
        current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1
      else
        current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id=>product_id)
        line_items << current_item
      end
        current_item
   end

  def total_price
   Array.wrap(line_items).sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end
```

my cart/show.html.rb

```
<div class="cart_title" >Your Cart</div>
    <table>
        <% for item in @cart.line_items %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price" ><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
        <tr class="total_line" >
        <td colspan="2" >Total</td>
        <td class="total_cell" ><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, :method => :delete,
        :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

my model/line_item.rb

```
def total_price
     if product.price 
       product.price = product.price * quantity
     else
        0.to_d
     end
   end
```

full trace

```
app/models/line_item.rb:14:in `*'
app/models/line_item.rb:14:in `total_price'
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_carts_show_html_erb___389431939__618846538'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `each'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `method_missing'
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb___389431939__618846538'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:250:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:43:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:268:in `block in retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:22:in `show'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__371692982__process_action__266900328__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

im having a problem in adding my first item in to my cart it fails but when adding second time it worked fine im just wondering if my adding product method is right?
thanks in advance more power to us!

** edit added information **

apon tracking the information i found out that in my first attemp of adding a item to the cart the quantity of my first attemp is not writing in the database, 1 default (example is  id 128) even though i added a default quaunty => 1 in my migration file.

my migragein file
20120218201140_add_quantity_to_line_item.rb

```
def self.up
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer, :default => 1
end
```

already rake db:migrate it still the default option is not working?

my database

```
id          product_id  cart_id     created_at                  updated_at                  quantity    price     
----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------------  --------------------------  ----------  ----------
127         18          37          2012-02-23 09:05:40.594604  2012-02-23 09:05:53.560155  1           321.11    
128         15          37          2012-02-23 09:07:53.013923  2012-02-23 09:07:53.013923              42.95
```

Comment: In your line_item model, you have a line that says `0.to_d`.  Is `to_d` a method you created?  Also, out of curiosity, what does product.price return before you do any operations on it?

Comment: no i didnt create the to_d method, uhm from my understanding it produce item price = product * the number of product im following agile web development rails other code are not working so i try to enhance it my self but not so sure about my code =/

Comment: What is `0.to_d` trying to accomplish?  If you're trying to create a decimal, use `0.to_f`.  If you're trying to return a price, rails has a built in method called [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) that might be useful to you.  **Edit:** Just noticed you used it in your view.

Comment: From the trace though, it looks like there is error when you try to multiply whatever `product.price` is.  Is `quantity` an integer?

Comment: im trying to return zero as decimal if the product price is nil? yes qunatity is an integer it is also what i suspect in so i created the 0.to_d statement

Comment: tried changing '0.to_d' to '0.to_f' but the bug that was added at first attemp and second attemp is not working now the button addto cart is always saying nil cannot concien bigdecimal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem with 
rolling back the migration 20120218201140_add_quantity_to_line_item.rb 
and migrate it again and it solved my problem thanks for the help
more power to us